# Fetch one-to-many relationships in coreData and put it into a tableview

Tags: swift, core-data, one-to-many

How can I fetch one-to-many relationships in core data and put it into a table view?

I have this as my data model for the User

[User CoreData Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syog5.png)

And this is my data model for Task

[Task CoreData Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiXRP.png)

How can I fetch the tasks for a specific user and put it into a tableView

I tried using user.tasks, however that returned an NSSet and I couldn't use that to make a dataset for the table view.

Should I use predicate instead to do this? This is what I have

```
    func handleCoreDataTask(){
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
    let dateSorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueDate", ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [dateSorter]
    //request.predicate = 
    taskResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                                   managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.manageContext,
                                                   sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                   cacheName: nil)
    taskResultController.delegate = self
    do{
        try taskResultController.performFetch()
    }
    catch{
        print("Perform Fetch error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service nor a "How do I do something?" answer service. If you have a code specific question, please ask it. Show the code you have tried and we will try to help.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this platform and programming in general. I updated the question and added the code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the inverse relationship to `User` in `Task` and add an appropriate predicate

```
let username = "Foo"
let request: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.name == %@", username)
let dateSorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueDate", ascending: false)
request.sortDescriptors = [dateSorter]
```

The way to create a new results controller is discouraged. Create the results controller lazily (once) and change predicate and sort descriptors dynamically.